# SetOptions[Plot, FIlling -> Axis] breaks SmoothHistogram of a CDF

Tags: plotting, bugs, histograms

**Bug introduced in 12.1 or earlier and persists through 13.3 .**

---

**UPDATE: I reached out to Wolfram, and they confirmed that it's a bug.**

I am using version 12.3. Here's a simple plot of some randomly generated data:

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 10^5];
SmoothHistogram[data, Automatic, "CDF"]
```

[image: the expected plot, a rising sigmoidal curve]

Looks good. Now I `SetOptions` for `Plot` (not for `SmoothHistogram`), because I have other plots in my notebook where I want the `Filling -> Axis`:

```
SetOptions[Plot, Filling -> Axis];
```

But, if I now go back and try to plot my CDF again:

```
SmoothHistogram[data, Automatic, "CDF"]
```

[image: spiky wrong plot]

What happened? It seems to only happen when I call for `SetOptions[Plot, Filling -> Axis]`. Doesn't happen for other options. If I call `SetOptions[Plot, Filling -> None]`, then I again get the correct plot for my `SmoothHistogram` of a CDF. This does not affect `SmoothHistogram` for a PDF.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I am on MMA 13.3 on Win10-64.

Comment: Reproducible on v12.2.0 on Win7-x64.

Comment: Please be sure to report this bug to Wolfram.